# How to query the two related transactions in different days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, sql-server-2012

If i have table consists of two columns one for the user id and the other for the finger print(attendance,leave) how to detect all the users whose (leave time ) in the next day of their first finger print?

```
USERID  CHECKTIME
2982    2015-03-11 09:08:10.000
2982    2015-03-11 20:13:57.000
2982    2015-03-12 08:43:35.000
2982    2015-03-13 04:54:57.000
2982    2015-03-13 05:01:03.000
2982    2015-03-13 19:24:11.000
2982    2015-03-14 10:28:26.000
2982    2015-03-15 04:55:03.000
2982    2015-03-15 05:01:24.000
```

Example : this user has a check in `2015-03-12` in `08:43:35.000` 
and its check out in the next day  `2015-03-13` in `04:54:57.000`

i want to query all the users who has cases like that considering the user may have more than two check-in-out in the same day so i want just the first and (the last in the next day)

Comment: But why don't you store if its check in or out? It's more or less impossible to know whatever it is if it's 1000's or rows. (And perhaps one is missing, because the person did sneak in/out once.)

Comment: @just_name  please feel free to give a feed back on [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29511717/3208640)

Comment: @just_name, sorry, there was a small problem with previous answer which revised, I just wanted to inform you this version is complete. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all users are checking correctly and there is no missed checktime.

Assume our *Schema* is:

```
create table tblchk (USERID int,  CHECKTIME datetime)
insert into tblchk values
(2982    ,'2015-03-11 09:08:10.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-11 20:13:57.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-12 08:43:35.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-13 04:54:57.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-13 05:01:03.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-13 19:24:11.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-14 10:28:26.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-15 04:55:03.000'),
(2982    ,'2015-03-15 05:01:24.000');
```

No we can use a `row number` to specify which record is for `enter time` and which is `exit time`, `ODD`s are enter and `Even`s are exit:

```
select userid,
       checktime,
       case row_number()over(partition by userid order by checktime)%2
            when 1 then 'Enter'
            else 'Exit'
       end [type]
from tblchk
```

result is:

```
userid  checktime               type
2982    2015-03-11 09:08:10.000 Enter
2982    2015-03-11 20:13:57.000 Exit
2982    2015-03-12 08:43:35.000 Enter
2982    2015-03-13 04:54:57.000 Exit
2982    2015-03-13 05:01:03.000 Enter
2982    2015-03-13 19:24:11.000 Exit
2982    2015-03-14 10:28:26.000 Enter
2982    2015-03-15 04:55:03.000 Exit
2982    2015-03-15 05:01:24.000 Enter
```

Now if we want to specify the days with last checktime is `enter` and the first checktime of the next day is `exit` we can use above query as:

```
with cte as
(
    select userid,
           checktime,
           row_number()over(partition by userid order by checktime) rn
    from tblchk
)

select q_enter.userid as [USER],
       q_enter.checktime as EnterTime, 
       q_exit.checktime as ExitTime
from
(
    select userid,
           max(checktime) checktime,
           max(rn) rn
    from cte 
    group by userid,cast(checktime as date)
    having max(rn)%2=1
)q_enter
join 
(
    select userid,
           min(checktime) checktime,
           min(rn) rn
    from cte 
    group by userid,cast(checktime as date)
    having min(rn)%2=0
)q_exit
on q_enter.userid=q_exit.userid and q_enter.rn=q_exit.rn-1
```

*Result:*

```
USER    EnterTime               ExitTime
2982    2015-03-12 08:43:35.000 2015-03-13 04:54:57.000
2982    2015-03-14 10:28:26.000 2015-03-15 04:55:03.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the aggregate functions like min and max which gives first in and last out values

you can check here 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68897/2

**SELECT USERID,MIN(CHECKTIME),MAX(CHECKTIME) FROM attendence GROUP BY USERID;**